# C# discard with ref operator

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

Is it possible to use C# 7 discard operator with ref operator instead of out.

Example:

```
int testInt;
if (!Int32.TryParse(AnyString, ref testInt)) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/discards):

> In C# 7.0, discards are supported in assignments in the following
>   contexts:
>
> Tuple and object deconstruction.
>   Pattern matching with `is` and `switch`.
>   **Calls to methods with `out` parameters.**
>   A standalone `_` when no `_` is in scope.

`int.TryParse` obviously expects an `out`-parameter. The operator you refer to doesn´t change that.

Apart from this `ref` implies that the value has already been initialized to some value in order to use it within the method. So effectivly `ref` is used when you need the provided value and change it afterwards, whereas `out` simply does not do anything with the provided value, it simply *returns* it. This is why you have to initialize a variable passed by `ref`, where you don´t need to do so for an `out`-parameter.

In other words. When you have a method that expects a `ref`-parameter you can use the provided value and use it in your method:

```
void DoSomething(ref int i)
{
    var a = i + 1;
    i = a;
}
```

This obviously assumes that `i` **has** a value set.

On the other hand you can´t do **anything** with a value passed as `out` inside the method:

```
void DoSomething(out int i)
{
    var a = i + 1;  // won´t compile because i has not been set
    i = a;
}
```

So why does the operator you refer to does not work for `ref`? It´s simply what I stated above: using `ref` assumes you **initialized** the value before passing it. However **you can´t initialize a discarded variable**.

Answer (score 3):

What you've written will not compile so I assume you're using it as an example. But no the discard operator cannot be used with ref. I'm not sure why you would even want too. If you have a use case where you would want to discard the output, just use out instead.

```
if (!Int32.TryParse(AnyString, out _)) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ref here. Instead, you sould use out parameter for discard. Sample code has given below:

```
if(!int.tryParse(yourString, out string _)){//Do something}
```